# how to use where statement with array

Tags: php, mysql

**I want to retrieve brand name using condition array to create json format.But,I can not get it.The result is "No record found.How can I do that it? **

```
<?

    $brand_array=array('sony','samsung');                  
        $data=implode(',',$brand_array);        
        $query_brand=mysql_query("SELECT ttdbrand.name
                                  FROM `taxonomy_term_data` as ttdbrand
                                  INNER JOIN
                                        `node` as n
                                  INNER JOIN        
                                        `field_data_field_brand` as fbrand
                                  ON n.nid=fbrand.entity_id
                                  AND ttdbrand.tid=fbrand.field_brand_tid                                 
                                  Where ttdbrand.name in ('$data')"                                              
                                  ) or die(mysql_error()) ;


        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_brand)) {         
            $row_array[]=$row;                 
        }
?>
```

Comment: check your query directly by running that in phpmyadmin, no issues with 'where' placement.

Comment: `INNER JOIN
                                        \`node\` as n`.... what are you joining on?

Comment: `SELECT ttdbrand.name
                                  FROM \`taxonomy_term_data\` as ttdbrand
                                  INNER JOIN        
                                        \`field_data_field_brand\` as fbrand
                                  ON ttdbrand.tid=fbrand.field_brand_tid                                 
                                  INNER JOIN
                                        \`node\` as n
                                  ON n.nid=fbrand.entity_id
                                  Where ttdbrand.name in ('$data')`

Comment: And `$data=implode(',',$brand_array);` needs to be `$data=implode("','",$brand_array);` to give you quotes around the individual brand strings

Comment: yes,it works!Thanks !

Comment: @MarkBaker shouldn't you post an answer instead of a comment?

Answer (score 0):

instead of array make string with values like
     you user array('a','b','c');

```
 run this array and make string 
 $str = '';
 e.g while (your array)
    $srt .= '\''.$value.'\''.',';

    $str look like 'a','b','c',

 after loop is over remove ',' rtrim and user this $str variable insted of $data
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace Here , to arrange string within quotes

```
 $data=implode(',',array_map(function($v){return "'".$v."'"},$brand_array));
```

Answer (score 0):

it is not working because this:

```
Where ttdbrand.name in ('$data')
```

Will result into this:

```
Where ttdbrand.name in (sony,samsung)   
//no quotation marks. you can't pass strings like that, sql will fail
```

Like @MarkBaker stated, you need to add quotes like:

```
$data=implode("','",$brand_array);
```